# Custome keyboard show pop up image cut off

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am working in custom keyboard app.

When long press in my emojis it's not open in above textField. it's display in bellow iMessage keyboard. see below screen shot.

[image]

it's possible to add my image open in above textField.like iOS default emojis.

[image]

if it's possible then give me solution, Thanks.

Comment: it's not a toolbar, it's default iOS iMessager app @AkshanshThakur

Comment: please share your code. I have faced this issue & also solved the same.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS How you solved the same issue?

Comment: As I can remember, I moved keyboard layer above all the views. Thats why I asked code from you :)

Comment: i did only add subview in keyboardController `[self.view addSubview:self.swemojis];` @Gagan_iOS

Comment: how can i moved keyboard layer above textField @Gagan_iOS

Comment: Yes, same code i wrote and it is top of the all view still i face the same issue @Gagan_iOS